Is it ok to ask if <problem> can be solved with <algorithm>
I have a problem/riddle. I want to know if it can be solved via linear programming, only - other, perfectly valid solutions would not constitute an answer. Is that a valid question here?
I think yes, because the question itself is a "creative riddle" and does not have to do with routine, despite the theory being a prerequosite.
Not sure if relevant, but its origin is also somewhat hobbyist - it's not like I present my work specs to see if business can be done this way. It's still a game behind.
This generalizes to the title for every such problem/solve type...probably.

Yes, this is a perfectly allowable question!
We allow questions about puzzles here, not just questions that are themselves puzzles. (In fact, in the very early days of the site, it was only the former type of question that was allowed!) Asking which solving methods are viable for a certain type of puzzle seems completely reasonable to me.
